# change the character NUL by enter in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am working on a bat file. I have a .txt file like this -

```
1:  04000025000          00000008,37 NULNULNULNUL
2:  04000455000          0465346000008,37 NULNULNULNUL
```

I want to delete all NUL for have -

```
1:  04000025000          00000008,37 
2:  04000455000          0465346000008,37
```

Coud you please help me ?

> The character for `NUL` is `\x00`

I need a bat code, which looks for the character `x00` in the txt file and replaces it with the character to go to the next line.

Like this:

```
powershell -Command "(MMAI_CONTRAT_20180519.txt) -replace %\x00% , '\n' | Out-File test.txt"
```

Comment: Please provide the [mcve] of the code you'd like us to help you with when editing your question according to the advice in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is that clear now ?

Comment: It is better now that I've edited it to format the code in a code box and include the relevant PowerShell tag! But there is still no question there because along with your code you have not explained to us what exactly happens when you run it, if that fails to run as written and intended, and what you've tried yourself in fixing the issue, if there is in fact an issue.

Comment: Have you actually tried the command in PowerShell, before trying to include it within your batch file? Are you aware of the following: `\`0 - Null`, `\`n - New line`, `\`r - Carriage return` and `\`r\`n - Carriage return + New line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Get-Content` missing in your command.

Provided the text file looks like this before

```
> (Get-Content MMAI_CONTRAT_20180519.txt)|Format-Hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   31 3A 20 20 30 34 30 30 30 30 32 35 30 30 30 20  1:  04000025000
00000010   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30           0000000
00000020   38 2C 33 37 20 00 00 00 00 32 3A 20 20 30 34 30  8,37 ....2:  040
00000030   30 30 34 35 35 30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  00455000
00000040   20 20 30 34 36 35 33 34 36 30 30 30 30 30 38 2C    0465346000008,
00000050   33 37 20 00 00 00 00                             37 ....
```

This should do the job:

```
> (Get-Content MMAI_CONTRAT_20180519.txt) -replace '\x00+', "`r`n"|Format-Hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   31 3A 20 20 30 34 30 30 30 30 32 35 30 30 30 20  1:  04000025000
00000010   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30           0000000
00000020   38 2C 33 37 20 0D 0A 32 3A 20 20 30 34 30 30 30  8,37 ..2:  04000
00000030   34 35 35 30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  455000
00000040   30 34 36 35 33 34 36 30 30 30 30 30 38 2C 33 37  0465346000008,37
00000050   20 0D 0A                                          ..
```

The command escaped and wrapped in batch:

```
 powershell -nop -c "(Get-Content MMAI_CONTRAT_20180519.txt) -replace '\x00+', \"`r`n\"| Out-File test.txt"
```

Comment: If the file size is doubled, it looks like the wrong encoding most likely UTF16. Otherwise replacing 4 zero bytes with CR/LF should reduce the size by two bytes per line.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with batch code ? When I copy past just the content in the another file, the file size become to 15 256 Ko

Comment: Either append an `-Encoding ascii` or OEM etc. or use `Set-Content test.txt`

Comment: It's perfect !! Thank you so much